# Xcode & Playground not displaying results window

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I am fairly new to programming, so I admit I have a lot to learn.  In earlier versions of Xcode and Playground, I used to see the results as I typed a program.  For example when typing
var str = "Hello, playground"  on the far right (results window) I would see:  Hello, playground.   I also had typed up part of a program with a function and if I entered values for variables, it would calculate the result in the result window (on the right).  At some point in typing program, it stopped showing this.

I was hoping that someone would be able to assist me in figuring out what happened.  I am thinking that with trying to learn the new Mac (I have always used a PC in the past) that I may have pressed some buttons somewhere that I should not have....OR the newest updates took away the function somehow? Here is what I have done:
-closed the application and restarted
-restarted the computer
-tried checking setting, but I am not too sure what to look for...
-called for support but they don't seem too sure either..
-installed the newest version available of Xcode (Xcode 7 beta) and rebooted

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be broken in 7B4, it is for me.  I can see a thread on devforums for this, but when I clicked the link, it redirected me to a create-account page and would not let me in.  When I tried to search for it from my account, I did not see it in the list.

See the thread shown in this (admittedly transient) search:

https://www.google.com/search?q=xcode+playground+not+showing+results&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Particularly, this result:

> Playground not displaying output | Apple Developer Forums
>   https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3672 Jun 9, 2015 - This
>   checks to see if the playground is operational. If it does not echo to
>   the results sidebar, try quitting and restarting Xcode. If you're
>   still not ...

Comment: Thanks for the info and reply!  I will try some of what is suggested on that forum. I am wondering if there is an issue with the update, though since Xcode was working for me until after new updates.  There are a couple of responses in a link that you provided that are worth trying, though.  I will gladly give them a shot.  Thanks.